# Using Minitest, how do I stub calls to several different class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, minitest, stub

How do I stub or mock calls to several different *class* methods when using Minitest?

For example, I want to test this method:

```
  def index
    categories = CategoryAnalyzer.for_user(current_user)
    @root_categories = categories.select { |c| c.parent_id.nil? }
    @max_depth = CategoryAnalyzer.max_depth(categories)
    @children_by_id = CategoryAnalyzer.children_by_id(categories)
  end
```

Notice that it calls three separate class methods on `CategoryAnalyzer`.  Is there a way to stub or mock all three methods (`for_user`, `max_depth`, and `children_by_id`) that doesn't require nesting one call to `stub` within the block of another call to `stub`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Minitest::Mock` class to create mock object and stub different methods on it.

for example -

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class UserProfileTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_index_method
    # Create a mock object
    category_analyzer_mock = Minitest::Mock.new
    # Stub the for_user method, for user categories
    category_analyzer_mock.expect(:for_user, mocked_categories, [mocked_user])
    # Stub the max_depth method
    category_analyzer_mock.expect(:max_depth, mocked_max_depth, [mocked_categories])

    # Replace the original MyCategories with the mock
    MyCategories.stub(:new, category_analyzer_mock) do
      #test code that calls index method
      #you can call the method on an instance of your controller
      controller = UserProfile.new
      controller.index

      # Assertions based on the expected behavior of your method
      assert_equal expected_root_categories, controller.instance_variable_get(:@root_categories)
      assert_equal expected_max_depth, controller.instance_variable_get(:@max_depth)
    end

    # Verify that the expected methods were called
    category_analyzer_mock.verify
  end

  private

  def mocked_user
    #return a mocked user
  end

  def mocked_categories
    #return mocked categories
  end

  def mocked_max_depth
    #return mocked value
  end
end
```

Comment: CategoryAnalyzer has only class methods, not instance methods. The program doesn't ever instantiate any CategoryAnalyzer objects.

Comment: its just an example, and we can use it to initialize the class and the type of objects to mock. Its just a blueprint to share my approach.

Comment: I get that.  But, to follow your blueprint, don't I either need to (1) Replace the `CategoryAnalyzer` _class_ with the mock object, or (2) Call both `CategoryAnalyzer.stub(:max_depth)` and `CategoryAnalyzer.stub(:children_by_id)`?  The problem is that I don't know how to do either (1) or (2) in a reasonably concise way.

Comment: You can try simply try  setting any value that is required to pass the test.Once thats done, you may play around to make it fail too based on your logic and changing the assertions above as per your need.